# Ruby way to view memory usage?

Tags: ruby, memory, ps

Is there a Ruby way to view the memory usage of the running process? I have been using exec (or backticks) to call out to 'ps' but I'd rather do something that isn't system-specific. I'm starting to build docker containers and the handling of 'ps' seems to be inconsistent.

I'd much rather have a Ruby-specific method/class/etc. to get the current run-time memory of the Ruby process.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/GC/Profiler.html

Comment: The [Get Process Memory](https://github.com/schneems/get_process_mem) gem might be of use to you.

Comment: @CarySwoveland https://github.com/schneems/get_process_mem/blob/master/lib/get_process_mem.rb#L15 It is not much more cross-platform than old good `ps` :)

Comment: Have you check [new relic gem](https://github.com/newrelic/rpm)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with combination of [rbtrace](https://github.com/tmm1/rbtrace)  and ObjectSpace.

```
rbtrace -p PID -e 'Thread.new{require "objspace"; ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations_start; GC.start(); ObjectSpace.dump_all(output: File.open("heap.json", "w"))}.join'
```

More info in the [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/samsaffron/why-ruby-2-dot-1-excites-me) by Sam Saffron.